# Python : Add a new Tab in Maya Main UI

Tags: python, user-interface, tabs, maya

I'm a beginner in programing in Maya, and I want to create a new Window INSIDE the main UI of Maya. The ideal place is in the same place that the attribute editor. I know it's possible because XGen does that, but I really do not find how :'(

[Like here !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcJ2T.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a window with maya.cmds scripting and make this window dockable in maya

https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/dockControl.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the [dockControl](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/dockControl.html) example:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

myWindow = cmds.window()
buttonForm = cmds.formLayout( parent = myWindow )
cmds.button( parent = buttonForm )
allowedAreas = ['right']
cmds.dockControl( area='right', content=myWindow, allowedArea=allowedAreas )
```

you can create any arbitrary window and enforce/allow it to dock at a specific location.

The above example will spawn and restrict 'myWindow' to the Right side of your UI, unless you undock it...

Extending the allowedAreas attribute gives more location options if you want to use them.

Comment: This does not create tab where "attribute Editor" is. How do i create similar docker to attribute editor.

Comment: Use `tabToControl` argument as described: Tab this workspace control into the given control. Example: `cmds.workspaceControl(name, tabToControl=["AttributeEditor", -1],  widthProperty="preferred", label=label)`